# How to prevent part of HTML page from rendering in rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, rendering

So this might be sort of a newbie question, but I have a multiple page form in my rails application, and I have the same background and title on each page of the form. I was wondering if it was possible for me to do something so that when I move to the next question in the form, only the next question renders, and the background and title can just stay the same. It just looks a little weird when a flash of white comes up every time I move to the next question when theres only a small part of the page changing each time.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard about [turbolinks](http://railscasts.com/episodes/390-turbolinks?view=asciicast) ?

Comment: I have it installed yet I still get the whiteness when I move to the next page. All I have changing is a question. Is there any way to just set a certain part to render when I load the next page? Are there anything like templates?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to a step by step wizard,and it really depends on how you are thinking on implementing it, via javascript or with the server(rails), a fast way is to use https://github.com/schneems/wicked which allows you to do this through a Rails controller, here is also a rails cast on that http://railscasts.com/episodes/346-wizard-forms-with-wicked